# Coverity Scan on GitLab pipeline failing

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner, coverity

Trying to run Coverity scan on python files, this Job is automated as pipeline on Gitlab.

Running the scan on runner with below kubernetes configuration:

```
  cpuLimit: 1500m
  # cpuLimitOverwriteMaxAllowed: 400m
  memoryLimit: 3Gi
  # memoryLimitOverwriteMaxAllowed: 512Mi
  cpuRequests: 1500m
  # cpuRequestsOverwriteMaxAllowed: 200m
  memoryRequests: 1500Mi
  # memoryRequestsOverwriteMaxAllowed: 256Mi
   
resources:
limits:
  memory: 3Gi
  cpu: 1500m
requests:
  memory: 3Gi
  cpu: 1500m
```

Running below commands:

1. cov-capture --source-dir $CI_PROJECT_DIR  --dir idir
2. cov-analyze --dir idir. --> This second command is failing with below.

I am suspecting something to do with my Kubernetes POD CPU and memory limits, pls suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, the problem is the analysis has exceeded the configured 3 GiB memory limit, and has been killed by the [OOM Killer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html).  You can confirm that diagnosis by using the `kubectl describe pod` command as described, for example, [here](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-oomkilled-exit-code-137/) or [here](https://sysdig.com/blog/troubleshoot-kubernetes-oom/).

The analysis memory requirements are documented at [Coverity Memory and CPU Requirements](https://sig-docs.synopsys.com/polaris/topics/cov-hardware-requirements.html), with the basic formula being:

> 1.0 GiB + (0.5 GiB * number of analysis workers)

The console output shown in your screenshot says:

```
Using 32 workers as limited by CPU(s)
```

That means, per the formula, that the analysis needs 17 GiB.  And it really will use all of that memory, even for a relatively small program, because it starts all of the workers immediately and each one will use its allotted 0.5 GiB.

By default, `cov-analyze` starts as many workers as there are CPU cores on the machine.  To stay under 3 GiB, you will need to pass `--jobs 4` in order to limit the number of workers to 4.  (I'd start with `--jobs 3` to be on the safe side.)